# Is there any function/implementation in python similar to peaks(N) in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I can obtain a 2D matrix/3D plot using `peaks(N)` where N is any number in MATLAB. Is there any way to do this in python?

MATLAB example:

Create a 5-by-5 matrix of peaks and display the surface:

```
figure
peaks(5);
```

[image]

How to do this in python?

Comment: https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/ something like that?

Comment: So, maybe this; https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-example-of-2d-density-plots-in-python-83b83b934f67

Answer (score 0):

You can use SciPy

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=0) # x is the signal

print("x-values: ", peaks," y-values: ",  x[peaks])
```

[SciPy documentation for finding peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

.. Or a quick solution if you signal is not too noisy then you can manually smooth the signal, differentiate the smoothed signal, find a threshold value and count the zeroes :)